# Git:Help to retrieve local commit in PyCharm, WebStorm

Tags: git, pycharm, webstorm, git-branch, git-commit

I made a branch called `1.3` from master, then

```
  $ git checkout 1.3
  $ git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/1.3
  $ git push -u origin/1.3
```

EDIT: I did a `git push -u origin master` before the above 3 steps if that makes any difference?

But somehow I lost the last local commit so meaning I can't even push to Bitbucket?

How to retrieve the last commit? Why is it lost or disappeared somewhere along the trace?

After generating ssh-key as personalid.

This is my ~/.ssh/config

```
  Host bitbucket.org 
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa 

#Default GitHub user 
Host github.com 
  HostName github.com 
  PreferredAuthentications publickey 
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/b


# Work user account 
Host bitbucket.org 
  HostName bitbucket.org 
  PreferredAuthentications publickey 
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/workid 

Host bitbucket.org 
  HostName bitbucket.org 
  PreferredAuthentications publickey 
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/personalid
```

Comment: Is that a `git checkout 1.3` or `git checkout -b 1.3` ?

Comment: Hi forevergenin : git checkout 1.3 as above

Comment: `git checkout 1.3` will not create a new branch. It will only checkout an already created branch. In your case it looks like there was already a branch named `1.3` and it got checked out. If you like to create a new branch from the currently checked out branch you have to run `git checkout -b 1.3`.

Answer (score 1):

If you remember the commit message for your last commit then you can easily recover it. If you don't remember any info the last commit then it becomes a bit difficult but still doable.

Run the command `git reflog`. It will list all the previous HEAD commits. Kinda like undo list. From this list note down the `git commit id` for your last commit. Now run `git checkout -b new_1.3 last-or-lost-commit-id`. The `new_1.3` will now have the lost commit as its HEAD.

If you like to push this new branch to the remote then run `git push origin -u new_1.3`.

Comment: Thanks forevergenin, only the git push origin -u new_1.3 didnt work, worked within PyCharm IDE VCS -> Git -> Push.  CLI returned : The server's host key is not cached in the registry. You
have no guarantee that the server is the computer you
think it is.
...
connection.
Store key in cache? (y/n) y. But just hangs there indefinitely...

Comment: Why was it the commit lost in the first place? Thanks

Comment: It was not lost. If my understanding is correct you have just switched your working copy from `master` to `1.3` when you ran `git checkout 1.3`.